# Write line to MATLAB from C#

Tags: c#, matlab

I want to write a line in the MATLAB command window from a C# method. This is the .NET code:

```
using System;

namespace SharpLab {
    public class Test {
        public void Run() {
            dynamic Matlab = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Matlab.Application"));
            Matlab.Execute("clc"); // This line does work.
            Matlab.Execute("disp('Hello world!')"); // This line does not work.
        }
    }
}
```

Now I load the library, create a class instance and run the method. This is the MATLAB code:

```
disp('This message goes to the command window. Can .NET call clc?');
NET.addAssembly('SharpLab.dll');
Test = SharpLab.Test;
Test.Run();
```

This does run and the command window is cleared by clc. The second call, 'Hello world!', does not work.

How can I print messages from C# in the MATLAB command window?

**EDIT**: I received a message linking to http://www.mathworks.nl/support/solutions/en/data/1-C9Y0IJ/index.html?product=SL&solut=. This solution collects all the written information into a variable to use, however the real function I am running does work for about a minute with a lot of messages in between. Waiting a minute before throwing a wall of text is not what I am after.

Comment: What is wrong with the solution you found? Can't you simply run that several times per minute/after each writeline command?

Comment: The solution mentioned in the edit will produce an output at the end of the .NET function completion. The function I invoke from DLL, however, should show messages at different stages of the method invocation. Note that it runs for about 30~60s, so having feedback at appropriate times is necessary. If you invoke an executable, it's stdout will appear in the console window, but this is not the case for a DLL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using [.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8627sbea.aspx) [events](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/events-and-delegates.html) to inform listeners that an event occurred, where you [register an event handler in MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/use-net-events-in-matlab.html) to do the actual printing.

Here is a toy example that finds all prime numbers up to 10000. First we create the C# library:

### MyClass.cs

```
using System;

namespace MyLibrary
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        // function that does some work and notify listeners of occurred events
        public void FindPrimes()
        {
            // Primes between 1 and 10000
            for (int i = 1; i < 10000; i++)
            {
                if (MyClass.isPrime(i))
                {
                    //System.Console.WriteLine(i);
                    onPrimeFound(i);
                }
            }
        }

        // helper function to determine if number is prime
        public static bool isPrime(int x)
        {
            if (x == 1) return false;
            if (x == 2) return true;
            for (int i = 2; i <= Math.Ceiling(Math.Sqrt(x)); i++)
            {
                if (x % i == 0) return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        // event broadcasted
        public event EventHandler PrimeFound;
        protected void onPrimeFound(int x)
        {
            var handler = this.PrimeFound;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PrimeEventArgs(x));
            }
        }
    }

    // event data passed to listeners
    public class PrimeEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public readonly int number;
        public PrimeEventArgs(int x)
        {
            this.number = x;
        }
    }
}
```

#### MATLAB

Next we use our class library inside MATLAB:

```
>> NET.addAssembly('C:\path\to\MyLibrary.dll');
>> c = MyLibrary.MyClass();
>> lh = addlistener(c, 'PrimeFound', @(o,e) fprintf('Prime: %d\n', e.number));
>> c.FindPrimes()
Prime: 2
Prime: 3
Prime: 5
...
Prime: 9973
```

The C# function `FindPrimes()` performs a lengthy operation, while emitting events to let interested observers know of occurred events (basically whenever you want to print something to MATLAB console). It should print immediately without buffering.

Comment: Brilliant. I did not think of this approach, thank you! For anyone whom is left wondering how to handle a `System.String`, just call `char` in MATLAB on it to convert it (e.g. `fprintf(1, '%s\n', char(e.message))`).

Answer (score 1):

A quick search has led me to believe that there are 2 ways to get output from a dll.

1. Writing it to a file, and then looking into it
2. Make sure that a console is created and then linking to it

I think the first one is the easiest way, but the second one is probably what you need.

Its hard for me to determine (and thus extract) the relevant part, but I believe [option two is described here](http://objectmix.com/smalltalk/182835-how-catch-stdout-externallibrary-dll.html).

Comment: 1: MATLAB will block when running .NET, therefore the result would be the same as capturing all output and showing it at the end of the method, instead of showing messages when they appear. 2: Smalltalk forum? Creating a console window isn't a problem in .NET, but attaching to it from MATLAB would be the issue.

Comment: @RoelvanUden It depends on why you want this, but if you are just interested in monitoring progress you can write to a log file and open it with a different program. (Non blocking editor like TextPad, or in theory even a second matlab session allowing you to update your view automatically).